# How to verify Jmeter 5.3 heap size?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have increased the heap size of the Jmeter 5.3 to 8 GB.
The lines which I have added in the jmeter.bat file are ass below:

```
if not defined HEAP (
  rem See the unix startup file for the rationale of the following parameters, 
  rem including some tuning recommendations 
  set HEAP=-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m 
  set NEW=-XX:NewSize-8192m -XX:MaxNewSize-8192m 
  rem set HEAP=-Xmalg -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize-256m
}
```

I have used below code in the JSR223 sampler

```
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().each {
log.info("Effective JVM argument: " + "$it")
}
```

but it is not working and showing error in the console.
I am using openJDK version 17

How can I verify whether 8 GB has been allocated or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue, if you need assistance you're expected to share your "error" details.

[image]

Heap size can be inspected using i.e. [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)

[image]

If you prefer doing this using JSR223 test elements and have problems with mbeans approach alternatively you can use [Runtime.maxMemory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory()) function like this:

```
println('Maximum heap size: ' + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 + ' GB')
```

when you run your test the maximum heap size will be printed to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))

[image]

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever it the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)